# Python3 : How to spawn jobs in parallel

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am pretty new to multithreading and would like to explore. I have a json file, that provides some config. Based on this, i need to kick off some processing. Here is the config

```
{
    "job1":{
        "param1":"val1",
        "param2":"val2"
    },
    "job2":{
        "param3":"val3",
        "param4":"val4"
    }
}
```

and here is the python snippet

```
config_file = open('config.json')
config_data = json.load(config_file)
for job_name,job_atts in metric_data.items():
    perform_job(job_name,job_atts)
```

so in this way, i can finish up the jobs one by one.

Is there a way to run/kick off these jobs in parallel? Note that these jobs are completely independent of each other and do not need to be performed in a seqeuence.

How can i achieve parallel runs via python?

**Update**

```
Here is what i tried

    >>> from multiprocessing import Pool
    >>> 
    >>> config_data = json.loads(''' {
    ...     "job1":{
    ...         "param1":"val1",
    ...         "param2":"val2"
    ...     },
    ...     "job2":{
    ...         "param3":"val3",
    ...         "param4":"val4"
    ...     }
    ... }''')
    >>> def perform_job(job_name,job_atts):
    ...     print(job_name)
    ...     print(job_atts)
    ... 
    >>> args = [(name, attrs)
    ...         for name, attrs in config_data.items()]
    >>> 
    >>> with Pool() as pool:
    ...     pool.starmap(perform_job, args)
    ... 
    Process SpawnPoolWorker-27:
    Process SpawnPoolWorker-24:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
        self.run()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 114, in worker
        task = get()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 368, in get
        return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
    AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'perform_job' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
        self.run()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 114, in worker
        task = get()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 368, in get
        return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
    AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'perform_job' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

But i am still getting the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the
[multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)
module.
Use a process pool to iterate over many jobs.

Here is an example source file that runs correctly when executed as `$ python spawn.py`.
Putting the main code within a `def main():` function is nice
but not critical.
Protecting it with an "if name..." clause *is* quite important,
since child interpreters will be re-parsing the source file, see "[safe importing of main](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming)".
(Notice that the "single core" test won't run within the children.)
The most relevant lines are the last two.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from multiprocessing import Pool
import json

config_data = json.loads(
    """ {
    "job1":{
        "param1":"val1",
        "param2":"val2"
    },
    "job2":{
        "param3":"val3",
        "param4":"val4"
    }
} """
)
args = list(config_data.items())


def perform_job(job_name, job_atts):
    print(job_name, job_atts)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Single core:
    perform_job(*args[0])
    perform_job(*args[1])
    print()

    # Multi core:
    with Pool() as pool:
        pool.starmap(perform_job, args)
```

[image: starmap]

Comment: thanks, i tried this approach but i get an error

`AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'perform_job' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>`

Comment: Let's try it on just single core. Right before the `with`, execute `perform_job(*args[0])`. Notice that it's crucially important to `import` (or `def`) that function before you attempt to execute it.

Comment: thanks @J_H, please see my latest update. in still get the error

Comment: The "usual rules" for putting together a python module are: (1.) mostly just do class / function `def`s, nothing crazy, no print()s or other side effects, (2.) protect "run it!" or other side effects inside an `if __name__ == "__main__":` clause. I will update the answer to reflect those bedrock assumptions. Please understand that the pool will fork off a pair of new python interpreters, and each of them will go parsing through the source file.

Answer (score 2):

Besides `multiprocessing` and `threading`, you can also use `concurrent.future`, which is high-level and simpler:

```py
import json
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def perform_job(name, atts):
    print(f"{name}: {atts}")


with open("config.json") as stream:
    config_data = json.load(stream)

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for job_name, job_atts in config_data.items():
        executor.submit(perform_job, job_name, job_atts)
```

Output:

```
job1: {'param1': 'val1', 'param2': 'val2'}
job2: {'param3': 'val3', 'param4': 'val4'}
```

## Update

If you want to use `multiprocessing.Pool`, you should put the main code inside a function:

```py
import json
from multiprocessing import Pool


def perform_job(name, atts):
    print(f"{name}: {atts}")


def main():
    with open("config.json") as stream:
        config_data = json.load(stream)

    with Pool() as pool:
        pool.starmap(perform_job, config_data.items())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output will be more or less the same as before.

Comment: For threadsafe code the ThreadPoolExecutor approach is simpler. OP did not describe `perform_job()` as being threadsafe, so it wasn't clear that a threaded solution would be helpful. And even if safety is a given, the single [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) will often pose trouble for app-level speedup. Keeping N cores busy with N subprocesses (N GILs) tends to be easier for a naïve user to begin with than working out how one thread may be blocking the forward progress of another thread. Hint: threads should strongly prefer check_call() over os.system().

Comment: Another option is to use joblib